# php echo working html code from mysql?

Tags: php, html, echo

I have a chunk of html code stored in a field in a mysql database. If i try and echo it out it just sits on the page as text. Is there a way to echo it out in a working fashion. ( Meaning the html displays what it is meant to display )

The code is stored in a varchar field and i used nl2br with special characters to insert it. The code display's as text but it is what it should be.

Again can i echo the code out in a working way?

EDIT - This is the code that is displayed on the page.

```
<img name="" src="http://www.mysite.com/assets/viewcart.png" width="114" height="48"alt="" />
```

and this is the code stored in the database.

```
&lt;img name=&quot;&quot; src=&quot;http://www.mysite.com/assets/viewcart.png&quot; width=&quot;114&quot; height=&quot;48&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; /&gt;
```

The Echo request i used to get the code out was a simple.

```
echo $row['htmlcode'];
```

Thanks for any help and examples.

Comment: if its valid html, on a valid html page then there should be no issue, post it so we can take a look

Comment: Should work. Can you please post some code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try running your text through [`html_entity_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) before `echo`ing it.

as in `echo html_entity_decode($row['htmlcode']);`

Comment: I'm stabbing in the dark here, as the OP said that he could see the HTML code (so either it was rendered as plaintext, or was encoded). I'm just guessing.

Comment: oh i know, just  saying is all, based on the question its as valid an answer as well any :-)

Comment: Have you got an example of how i can use html_entity_decode with the echo.